# Prevent user from unpinning items on the taskbar on Windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-10, taskbar, group-policy

We have some laptops which go out to end users when they need to go to events however a few users seem to then go an unpin everything from the taskbar which makes my life a little frustrating when it comes to doing a health check and clean up afterwards

Is there like a local policy I could set on the machines that would prevent from items from being unpinned on the taskbar?

Comment: Why not just reimage them as a standard part of your process?

Comment: That is a possibility however sometimes we don't have time to do that, sometimes i'll get a laptop back and it needs to go out to another user that same day and although the imaging process doesn't take long we use SCCM to push updates and applications which is what takes the time

Comment: @pun That gives me the answer i'm looking for :) thanks